Arena indextree - the Node vanishes
When using insert_after() to insert the group with the nodes [3, 4] after the group with the nodes [1, 2] Node c [3] and Node d [4] will get disconnected.
use indextree::Arena;

fn main() {
    // create a new arena and add some nodes to the arena
    let arena = &mut Arena::new();
    let a = arena.new_node(1);
    let b = arena.new_node(2);
    let c = arena.new_node(3);
    let d = arena.new_node(4);
    
    // append b after a
    a.insert_after(b, arena);
    let iter = a.following_siblings(arena);
    for n in iter {
        println!("{:?}", n);
    }
    println!();
    // append d after c
    c.insert_after(d, arena);
    let iter = c.following_siblings(arena);
    for n in iter {
        println!("{:?}", n);
    }
    println!();
    // append c after b - disconnects d from c
    b.insert_after(c, arena);
    let iter = a.following_siblings(arena);
    for n in iter {
        println!("{:?}", n);
    }
}

What is the ideomatic and correct way to join both groups?

The only connection between c and d is that they both have the same parent, so adding c as a "new sibling after this node." (which implies "to the same parent") changes cs parent to be the same as bs. That action cannot keep the "same parent" relationship c and d have.
So you'll have to change all (following_)siblings of c with it:
    // use `Vec::from_iter` to iterate eagerly so we don't keep borrowing `arena`
    let reverse_following_siblings = Vec::from_iter(c.following_siblings(arena)).into_iter().rev();
    for n in reverse_following_siblings {
        b.insert_after(n, arena);
    }


The task to change the parent of the follower of d is programmatically nicely solved.
However, I still believe it would be more ideomatic if this has already been done by insert_after(). Adding c to b as a sibling should not break the sibling relationship between c and d.

Yes it should, because changing one nodes parent shouldn't change any other node. That would be highly surprising. You're expecting siblings to be in a sort of linked list, when they aren't.

Worth to mention the parent() value of all nodes remains None at all times…

While it is true that there is no explic parent with a Node to identify, there is still an implicit parent of each new node without an id, see for example the comments in the second example of previous_sibling denoted as (implicit). Also having different behavior depending on if there is an explicit parent or not would be even more unpredictable and confusing.
